# Get Metadata from JPA EntityManager

Tags: hibernate

My project uses hibernate 5 with jpa and thus there is no hibernate config but a persistence.xml. I need to access the hibernate meta data to get to the PersistentClass.

So far I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780664/hibernate-migration-from-4-3-x-to-5-x-for-method-org-hibernate-cfg-configuration) information telling me to implement a `SessionFactoryBuilderFactory` as a Java service. However, the implemented `getSessionFactoryBuilder` is never called. (Maybe it is because the bootstrapping process is different with JPA?)

I have access to `HibernateEntityManagerFactory` and thus `SessionFactory`. Is there a way to access `MetadataImplementor` from here? Or can I get access to the `MetadataImplementor` (or PersistentClasses) from the JPA EntityManager?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply cast the `MetaModel` returned from your `EntityManager` like this:

```
MetamodelImplementor model = (MetamodelImplementor) em.getMetamodel();
```