# Hibernate upgrade to 5.2 - Session Factory creation and replacing PersistentClass for getting entity class properties

Tags: java, hibernate, migration, sessionfactory

I am currently upgrading my Hibernate version to the latest version 5.2.10. I replaced my code in the HibernateUtil for the SessionFactory creation.

**4.3.11.Final (Previous)**:

```
 public class HibernateUtil {
   private HibernateUtil() {}

   private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private static Configuration configuration;

    public static Configuration getConfiguration() {
        return configuration;
    }
    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
                     if(sessionFactory == null) {
                        configuration = new Configuration();
                        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
                        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
                        sessionFactory = configuration
                                .buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
                     }
            return sessionFactory;
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }

    }
    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static Session getSession() {
        Session hibernateSession = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        return hibernateSession;
      }

    public static void shutdown() {
       getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

**5.2.10 Final (New):**

```
public class HibernateUtil {
  private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
  private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return buildSessionFactory();
   }

  public static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
      try {
        registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").build();
        MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);
        Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();
        sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        shutdown();
      }
    }
    return sessionFactory;
  }

public static Session getSession() {
        Session hibernateSession = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        return hibernateSession;
      }

  public static void shutdown() {
    if (registry != null) {
      StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
    }
  }
}
```

Now I have a method which would fetch me the list of column names by passing the DB table name as a string. I did it like this before in 4.3.11.Final:

```
public static List<String> getColumnNames(String tableName) {

        List<String> columnList=null;

        Map<String, ClassMetadata> map = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getAllClassMetadata();
        Iterator<Entry<String, ClassMetadata>>  itr =  map.entrySet().iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()){

            ClassMetadata classMetaData = itr.next().getValue();
            AbstractEntityPersister aep = (AbstractEntityPersister) classMetaData;

            if(aep.getTableName().split("\\.")[1].equalsIgnoreCase(tableName)){

                columnList = new ArrayList<String>();
                String[] propertyNames = classMetaData.getPropertyNames();

                for(String property : propertyNames){
                        try {
                            PersistentClass persistentClass = HibernateUtil .getConfiguration().getClassMapping(classMetaData.getEntityName());
                            String clmName =  ((Column) persistentClass.getProperty(property).getColumnIterator().next()).getName();
                            columnList.add(clmName);
                        } catch(NoSuchElementException e){
                            log.error("Element not found idenfied as : "+property);
                        } catch(Exception e){
                            log.error(e.getMessage());
                        }
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        return columnList;
    }
```

Now after the upgrade it shows the method getAllClassMetadata as deprecated and am facing difficulty to get the PersistentClass object. I saw a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780664/hibernate-migration-from-4-3-x-to-5-x-for-method-org-hibernate-cfg-configuration) but I couldn't exactly figure out the solution. What part of my current code do I have to change for my getColumnNames() method to work exactly like before. I referred the documentation and it says to use the  `EntityManagerFactory.getMetamodel()` instead but i can't find suitable reference examples of the same. Also will I have to change the SessionFactory creation mechanism for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well finally I did it thank's to Vlad's article. I took the integrator code without any change and modified my `HibernateUtil` and the `getColumns()` method. So here's my code:

**SessionFactory creation:**

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return buildSessionFactory();
    }

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        final BootstrapServiceRegistry bootstrapServiceRegistry = new BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder().enableAutoClose()
                .applyIntegrator(MetadataExtractorIntegrator.INSTANCE).build();

        final StandardServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder(bootstrapServiceRegistry).configure().build();
        return new MetadataSources(serviceRegistry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static Session getSession() {
        Session hibernateSession = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        return hibernateSession;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }
}
```

**Metadata Extractor(Get Column names):**

```
public static List<String> getColumnNames(String tableName) {

    List<String> columnList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Namespace namespace : MetadataExtractorIntegrator.INSTANCE.getDatabase().getNamespaces()) {
        for (Table table : namespace.getTables()) {
            if (table.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(lookupTableName)) {
                Iterator<Column> iterator = table.getColumnIterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    columnList.add(iterator.next().getName());
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!columnList.isEmpty())
            break;
    }
    return columnList;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

First, we need to create a new [`MetadataExtractorIntegrator`](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-get-access-to-database-table-metadata-with-hibernate-5/) class that implements the Hibernate `Integrator`:

```
public class MetadataExtractorIntegrator 
    implements org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator {

    public static final MetadataExtractorIntegrator INSTANCE = 
        new MetadataExtractorIntegrator();

    private Database database;

    @Override
    public void integrate(
            Metadata metadata,
            SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
            SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {

        database = metadata.getDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void disintegrate(
        SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
        SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {

    }

    public Database getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }
}
```

Then, we can just configure Hibernate to use it.

If you're using the Hibernate bootstrap mechanism, then you can add it like this:

```
final BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder bsrb = new BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder();
bsrb.enableAutoClose();

Integrator integrator = integrator();
if (integrator != null) {
    bsrb.applyIntegrator( integrator );
}

final BootstrapServiceRegistry bsr = bsrb.build();

final StandardServiceRegistryBuilder ssrb = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder(bsr);
```

If you're bootstrapping with JPA, then you can do it as follows:

```
protected EntityManagerFactory newEntityManagerFactory() {
    PersistenceUnitInfo persistenceUnitInfo = persistenceUnitInfo(
        getClass().getSimpleName()
    );
    
    Map<String, Object> configuration = new HashMap<>();
    
    
    configuration.put("hibernate.integrator_provider", 
        (IntegratorProvider) () -> Collections.singletonList( MetadataExtractorIntegrator.INSTANCE )
    );

    EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl entityManagerFactoryBuilder = new EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl(
            new PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor(persistenceUnitInfo), configuration
    );
    return entityManagerFactoryBuilder.build();
}
```

Now, when running the following test:

```
for(Namespace namespace : MetadataExtractorIntegrator.INSTANCE
    .getDatabase()
    .getNamespaces()) {
     
    for( Table table : namespace.getTables()) {
        LOGGER.info( "Table {} has the following columns: {}",
             table,
             StreamSupport.stream(
                Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize( 
                    table.getColumnIterator(), 
                    Spliterator.ORDERED
                ), 
                false
            )
            .collect( Collectors.toList()) 
        );
    }
}
```

Hibernate outputs all the currently mapped tables in the log:

```
Table org.hibernate.mapping.Table(post) has the following columns: [
    org.hibernate.mapping.Column(id), 
    org.hibernate.mapping.Column(title), 
    org.hibernate.mapping.Column(version)
]
Table org.hibernate.mapping.Table(post_comment) has the following columns: [
    org.hibernate.mapping.Column(id), 
    org.hibernate.mapping.Column(review), 
    org.hibernate.mapping.Column(version), 
    org.hibernate.mapping.Column(post_id)
]
Table org.hibernate.mapping.Table(post_details) has the following columns: [
    org.hibernate.mapping.Column(id), 
    org.hibernate.mapping.Column(created_by), 
    org.hibernate.mapping.Column(created_on), 
    org.hibernate.mapping.Column(version)
]
Table org.hibernate.mapping.Table(post_tag) has the following columns: [
    org.hibernate.mapping.Column(post_id), 
    org.hibernate.mapping.Column(tag_id)
]
Table org.hibernate.mapping.Table(tag) has the following columns: [
    org.hibernate.mapping.Column(id), 
    org.hibernate.mapping.Column(name), 
    org.hibernate.mapping.Column(version)
]
```

That's it!

Comment: Thanks @Vlad for your answer. So will I have to replace my HibernateUtil class code that I mentioned above with the Hibernate bootstrap mechanism that you suggested? Also can you explain a bit more about this as this mechanism is relatively new to me. How does it read the configuration as der's no hibernate.cfg.xml in your code.The line Integrator integrator = integrator() refers to which integrator method? Also in the test method, the namespace.getTables(), is it part of org.hibernate.boot.relational.Namespace. Also how can i get the column name?

Answer (score 0):

#### As of Hibernate - 5.4.30.Final - released March 19th, 2021

The code below works and is **not deprecated** :

```
MetamodelImplementor metaModelImpl = (MetamodelImplementor)session.getMetamodel();
Map<String, EntityPersister> entityPersisters = metaModelImpl.entityPersisters();
Collection<EntityPersister> val = entityPersisters.values();               

for (EntityPersister ep : val) {
        AbstractEntityPersister aep = (AbstractEntityPersister)ep;

        System.out.println(aep.getTableName());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aep.getIdentifierColumnNames()));
        for (String propName : aep.getPropertyNames()) {
               System.out.println(propName);
               System.out.println(Arrays.toString(aep.getPropertyColumnNames(propName)));
        }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

An easier way to get column name with hibernate 5

```
final AbstractEntityPersister classMetadata = (AbstractEntityPersister) sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(clazz)
final String[] names = classMetadata.getPropertyColumnNames(property)
```

Comment: The Hibernate-SessionFactory-method `getClassMetadata` is also deprecated

Comment: Not according hibernate docs
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html

Comment: In 5.1 not yet - but starting with 5.2 it is deprecated (the question concerned version 5.2.10): https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getClassMetadata-java.lang.Class-