# Which dependencies are necessary in hibernate 5.2.13?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I am upgrading my hibernate project and hibernate dependencies from 3 to 5.2.13.Final  and I am changing my code to build `SessionFactory`  and i found some articles like [first](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-get-access-to-database-table-metadata-with-hibernate-5/)  
 and [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43604928/hibernate-upgrade-to-5-2-session-factory-creation-and-replacing-persistentclas)
 and all of them are using instance `MetadataExtractorIntegrator.INSTANCE` but I don't have this kind of class(MetadataExtractorIntegrator) in my dependencies ( maven project ) and can not find any dependency which is implementing this class. Can you help me which dependency do I need ?

Comment: Both of your links have code snippets for that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, `MetadataExtractorIntegrator` is class written in aricle you have mentioned. Just create such class and probably copy-paste it. What you need `Integrator` interface and that is included in Hibernate's ORM

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/tree/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/integrator/spi