# Search for java class using reflection with persistence unit

Tags: java, jpa, reflection, reflections

I want to search for a Java class using reflection with persistence unit. Now I'm using the search with the package name

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.entites");
Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class);
```

Comment: that code seems fine. what is the problem?

Comment: just told you wanna use the persisent unit name to do the search

Comment: What do you mean by the persistence unit name?

Comment: take a look here https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/persistence-unit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting all mapped Entities from EntityManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007073/getting-all-mapped-entities-from-entitymanager)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have persistense unit then you have classes names (inside `<class>...</class>`) and you can get `Class` objects using `Class.forName("com.entites.MyEntity")`.

For example you can programmatically read `persistence.xml` file if necessary.

I guess persisent unit name (`<persistence-unit name="...">`) is irrelevant to reflections.